# TextGeometry to always face user?

Tags: three.js

I've added some text to my scene with THREE.TextGeometry, and the text seems to be stuck in whichever xy plane I place it. Any way to have it adjust to always be in plane with the screen- readable for the user?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
mesh.lookAt( camera.position );
```

The local z-axis of the mesh should then point toward the camera.

Comment: cool this adjusts it, now how do i get it to update as i move the camera around?

Comment: If you have a `render()` function, place it in there, after any changes to the camera position.

Comment: hmm, getting closer, but now it stays fixed on the screen instead of moving around with the rest of the scene

Comment: Can you provide a live example, or a zip of your project? If not, your code source?

Comment: var BCx = new THREE.TextGeometry()
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( BCx, linecolor );
mesh.position.set(-75,-217,0)
textgroup.children.push(mesh);
scene.addObject( textgroup );
function render() {

textgroup.lookAt(camera.position);
 renderer.render( scene, camera );

 }

Comment: I have buttons that move the camera to front, right, top, and isometric views, and when I switch my text stays in the same screen coordinate

Comment: This is now a different issue. Please accept this answer by clicking on the green checkmark, and then post a new issue describing your problem. I can tell you that it will be very difficult to help you without complete source code -- there appears to be several other problems now, based on the snippets you provided.

Comment: @user1750723 You should be using HTML and CSS for that kind of stuff.

Comment: @mrdoob i know text has always been a bit tough in three.js but, it's still the case that using HTML and CSS only works for overlaying on top of a scene where you don't need to worry about occlusion, or care if the text is at a certain place in z depth, right?

Answer (score 14):

To make the text always face the screen (rather than the camera):

`mesh.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);`

Note that this differs from `object.lookAt(camera);` since this will result in different orientation depending on where on the screen the object is located.
[`Object3D.onBeforeRender`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D) can be used to update the orientation on each frame. It might be useful to disable frustum culling using `Object3D.frustumCulled = false;` to ensure that the callback always is triggered.

Comment: three.js is quaternion-based. So `mesh.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion );` is preferable.

Comment: @WestLangley: changed to quaternion.