# Three.js plane facing away from camera aligned with viewport

Tags: three.js, orientation, webgl

I'm trying to have a plane face away from the camera with same orientation so it's aligned in the viewport.

I have a plane in front of the camera, perfectly aligned to the cameras viewport, and I want to flip it in front of the camera, along the objects Y axis, regardless of camera orientation.

The following will orient my plane to face at the camera and works for any orientation:

```
target.rotation.copy(camera.rotation);
```

The following will then flip the plane along the plane's Y axis:

```
target.rotation.y += Math.PI;
```

All good so far? Except when the camera rotation has a funky tilt to it, let's say it's looking up and to the left, tilted slightly to the right, the plane's flip is tilted, but not the same way as the camera, leaving me with a plane tilted either to the left or right...

I've tried several things such as:

```
target.rotation.z -= camera.rotation.z;
```

Nothing... Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want a plane in front of the camera but facing away from the camera? May I ask why, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have double sided planes, 2 faces per plane geometry and 2 different materials. Think of a card flipping game and also see here for double faced planes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17602666/1060487

Answer (score 1):

So the problem I was running into was when the camera was in negative z coordinates. This causes the flip on the Y axis to get messed up.

So basically you would do something like this:

```
    var target = new THREE.Object3D();
    //position
    target.position.copy(s.camera.position);
    target.position.add(THREE.Utils.cameraLookDir(s.camera).multiplyScalar(300));
    //rotation
    target.rotation.copy(s.camera.rotation);
    target.rotation.y += PI;
    target.rotation.z = -s.camera.rotation.z;
    if (s.camera.position.z < 0) {
        target.rotation.z = s.camera.rotation.z;
    }
```

EDIT:

Add the following to appropriate spots in your program.

```
camera.rotation.eulerOrder = 'XZY';
target.rotation.eulerOrder = 'XZY';
```

Seems to solve previously encountered tilt issues! (see below)

RESOLVED:

Flipped planes tilted the wrong way in some instances, for example when in negative z coords and also the y rotation is not equal to 0, example: point in space hovering and looking at 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Try setting both the camera and target `rotation.eulerOrder = 'XZY' -- i.e., Y is last. Then `target.rotation.copy(s.camera.rotation); target.rotation.y += PI;`.

Comment: You sir are a scholar! That suggestion combined with my answer looks like it solves all cases. You still must change the rotation.z as I showed above but now I have no weird tilt issues in several orientations. Muchos Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I was looking for when I found this page (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919638/textgeometry-to-always-face-user) answer):

```
mesh.lookAt( camera.position );
```

The local z-axis of the mesh should then point toward the camera.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all... looking for a plane facing away from the camera, please read the question.